# Error when creating a Jekyll project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

When I run `jekyll new .` I have get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/lib/jekyll.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- public_suffix (LoadError)
```

**error just for `jekyll new .` and `jekyll new blog` worked successfuly
( i tested `jekyll new . --force` but problem is unsolved**

and my PATH is:

```
/home/shahrvand/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/shahrvand/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
```

and my ruby version is:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gem version : 2.7.7
jekyll 3.8.3
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. What does this error mean?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `public_suffix` gem. How did you install jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the `public_suffix` gem. Try installing via `gem install public_suffix` or put it into your `Gemfile` and re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: i install `public_suffix` but problem is still unresolved. i thinking problem for init jekyll in current directory. i tested with `--force` switch but not worked.